# How to bring only filtered data by passing id in a JSON File using jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to bring only filtered data from JSON file.

Is there someway, I can put where condition in ajax call like we do in SQL query.

In my page, I have three drop downlists as below:-

```
<select id="artistsList">
  <option value="-1"> Select Artist </option>
  <option value="1">Artist Abc</option>
  <option value="2">Artist Xyz </option>
</select>

<select id="moviesList">
<option value="-1"> Select Movie</option>
<option value="-1"> Abc Movie</option>
<option value="-1"> Xyz Movie Artist </option>
</select>

<select id="songsList">
 <option value="-1"> Select Songs</option>
 <option value="-1"> Abc Songs</option>
 <option value="-1"> Xyz Songs</option>
</select>
```

Plus, I have JSON file in my App_Data folder named data.JSON as below:-

```
//json file
[
 {

 "id": 1,
 "movie": "Abc Movie",
 "song": "Abc Songs"
  }, 
 {
 "id": 2,
 "movie": "Xyz Movie",
 "song": "Xyz Songs"
 }
]

 //jQuery
 $(document).ready(function (e)
  {
  var getArtistDetails = function (artistId) {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: '/App_Data/data.json',
            data: { 'artistId': artistId },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) 
           {
              //need to set the dropdown options as returned data
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }


        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

$('#artistsList').change(function (e)
{
    var selectedValue = parseInt($(this).val());

    console.log(selectedValue);
    switch(selectedValue)
    {
        case 1:
            getArtistDetails(selectedValue);
            break;
        case 2:
            getArtistDetails(selectedValue);
            break;
        case 3:
            getArtistDetails(selectedValue);
            break;
        case 4:
            getArtistDetails(selectedValue);
            break;
        default:
            alert('invalid');
            break;

    }



})
})
```

### Now my requirement is such that basis on the selection of first dropdownlist,I need to pass artistId & set the dropdown options of other two.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend something like (within your success callback from your Ajax request):-

```
...
success: function (data) {
  var movieList = document.querySelector('#moviesList')
  var songList = document.querySelector('#songsList ')
  movieList.innerHTML = ''
  songList.innerHTML = ''
  var movieListOption = null
  data.forEach(function (item) {
    movieListOption = document.createElement('option')
    movieListOption.setAttribute('value', item.id)
    movieListOption.textContent = item.movie
    movieList.appendChild(movieListOption)

    songListOption = document.createElement('option')
    songListOption.setAttribute('value', item.id)
    songListOption.textContent = item.song
    songList.appendChild(songListOption)
  });
}
...
```

happy coding

Comment: how do I filter data based on id passed, here JSON file is data source? if its db then where claused can easily filter but in JSON file how do I do that?

Comment: You would use something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter to filter though the results matching to a given condition and returning a new array with only the results that match the condition.